# VS_Code : Shell Integration Failed To Activate

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i hover on my vscode terminal name: (in terminal's upper right corner named "Powershell")

it shows : shell intergartion failed to activate,

how to solve this error, while

I tried installing vs code again but still no change, and also installed powershell 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few potential solutions for this issue.

Make sure that you have the latest version of VS Code and the Shell Integrate extension installed.

Check that the integrated terminal in VS Code is set to the shell you want to use (e.g. PowerShell, Command Prompt, Bash).

Try running VS Code as an administrator.

If you are using Windows, try adding the path of the shell you want to use (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe) to the "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" setting in your VS Code settings.

You can also try reinstalling vscode and the extension.
If none of the above solutions work, you can try searching for specific error messages in the output panel of vscode or in the output of the terminal.